# What is $P[X_1<X_2]$ and $P[X_1<\min(X_2,\ldots,X_j)]$ for i.i.d. continuous $X_i$?

Tags: probability

For $ X_1, X_2, . . ., X_n$ iid continuous random variables I need to find (a) $ P [X_1 < X_2]$ and b) $P[X_1 < \min(X_2,X_3,...,X_j)]$, where $j = 3,4,...,n$.

In my attempt of solving a I got the following:

$P(X_1<X_2)= \int_{support of X} P(X_1<X_2|X_2=x)P(X_2=x)dx \stackrel{iid}{=}\int_{support of X} P(X_1<X_2)P(X_2=x)dx = \int_{support of X} F_x(x)f_x(x)dx$.

Then I am not sure if this is where I need to stop or I can take my answer further. Same for point (b); I got the following:

$P[X_1 < \min(X_2,X_3,...,X_j)]=\int_{\text{support min}}P[X_1 < \min(X_2,X_3,...,X_j)|\min(X_2,X_3,...,X_j)=Y]P(\min(X_2,X_3,...,X_j)=y)dy \stackrel{iid}{=}\int_{\text{support min}} F_X(y)f_{\min}(y)dy$.

I am thinking that the way I solved the problem is too simple and I am missing an important property that I need to apply for this problem. I would appreciate any suggestions or help in solving this problem.

Comment: Isn't $P[x_1 > x_2] = P[x_2 > x_1] = 1/2$?  Isn't the probability of any single value being the minimum the same, and hence $P = 1/n$?

Comment: Is this a question about order statistics? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Would you mind showing me how to prove those identities?

Comment: @user762914 Yes it's about order statistics.

Comment: @EM823823:  Given $P[x_i > x_j]$ you can rename each $x_i$ by a permutation...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't understand what you mean by saying that we "can rename each $x_i$ by a permutation".

Answer (score 1):

For (b), the distribution of the min of $n-1$ draws from $F$ is $F_{min}(x) = F(x)^{n-1}$, with density $f_{\min}(x) = (n-1)F(x)^{n-2}f(x)$. So
$$
Pr[x < x_{\min}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underbrace{f_{min}(x_{min})}_{\text{Density of the min draw}} \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{x_{min}}zf(z)dz}_{\text{Pr remaining draw is less than the min draw}} dx_{min} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n-1)F(x)^{n-2}f(x)F(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n-1)F(x)^{n-1}f(x)dx. 
$$

For (a), the probability that $x_1 < x_2$ is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x_2) \int_{-\infty}^{x_2} f(x_1)dx_1 dx_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x_2) F(x_2) dx_2.
$$
$F^{-1}(u)=x$ is uniformly distributed, so a change of variable gives you that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)F(z)dz = \int_0^1 1u du = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot about the Uniform distribution of $F_x$!! In you solution to part (b) I don't understand where did z come from in the Pr remaining draw is less than the min draw?

Comment: Just a dummy variable of integration, that's the $X_1$ that you've left out, since you're taking the min over $x_2, ..., x_n$, giving you that sample of $n-1$ draws.

Comment: After working the problem out on my own, following your chain of thoughts, I realized that we are choosing the min form j-1 terms and $f_{min} = (j-1)f_X(x)[1-F_X(x)]^{j-2}$. Then the answer should be $\frac{1}{j}$ exactly what David G Stork said.